# Python pisa(xhtml2pdf) - Unable to generate Fixed portions of html

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, pdf-generation, pisa

I'm using python to generate pdfs based on an existing html template using the below code. The pdf prints ok, but it skips all the gaps between text. For instance, in the first page, some text is printer on the footer, but in the pdf it prints the footer text immediately without the gap.
However, when I open the html in browser, the footer is printed properly at the bottom! Any ideas to what might be the issue?

class GeneratePdf(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=will.pdf'
        will = Will()
        will.name="Albus Dumbledore"
        will.children = "Aberforth Dumbledore"
        will.partner = "Harry Potter"
        will.address = "Hogwarts school of w & w."
        will.exec1_name = "Severus Snape"
        will.exec1_address = "Surrey"
        will.guardian_name="Prongs"
        will.guardian_address="Dept of Mysteries"
        will.children="Ariana & Aberforth"
        will.funeral_preference="@hogwarts"

```
    f=open('template.htm','r')
    sourceHtml = f.read()
    f.close()
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__name__',will.name)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__address__',will.address)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__partner1__',will.partner)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__exec1_name__',will.exec1_name)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__exec1_address__',will.exec1_address)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__guardian_name__',will.guardian_name)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__guardian_address__',will.guardian_address)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__children__',will.children)
    sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__funeral_preference__',will.funeral_preference)
    pisa.CreatePDF(sourceHtml,dest=self.response.out)
    pisa.pisaDocument(sourceHtml,dest=self.response.out)
```

EDIT: Here is how template.htm starts:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<TITLE>Created by BCL easyConverter SDK 3 (HTML Version)</TITLE>
<META name="generator" content="BCL easyConverter SDK 3.0.60">
<STYLE type="text/css">

body {margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;}

#page_1 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 133px 0px 132px 120px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 673px;}
#page_1 #id_1 {border:none;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 486px;overflow: hidden;}
#page_1 #id_2 {border:none;margin: 769px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 673px;overflow: hidden;}

#page_1 #dimg1 {position:absolute;top:68px;left:0px;z-index:-1;width:554px;height:1px;font-size: 1px;line-height:nHeight;}
#page_1 #dimg1 #img1 {width:554px;height:1px;}




#page_2 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 37px 0px 78px 120px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 673px;}





#page_3 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 37px 0px 78px 120px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 673px;}





#page_4 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 37px 0px 78px 120px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 673px;}





#page_5 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 37px 0px 78px 120px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 673px;}





#page_6 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 37px 0px 152px 0px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 793px;}





#page_7 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 37px 0px 1043px 0px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 793px;}





.ft0{font: 30px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 35px;}
.ft1{font: bold 16px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 19px;}
.ft2{font: 16px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 18px;}
.ft3{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 17px;}
.ft4{font: bold 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 9px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft5{font: bold 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 18px;}
.ft6{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 5px;line-height: 17px;}
.ft7{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 4px;line-height: 20px;}
.ft8{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 20px;}
.ft9{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 2px;line-height: 20px;}
.ft10{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 19px;}
.ft11{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 19px;}
.ft12{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 2px;line-height: 22px;}
.ft13{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 22px;}
.ft14{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 22px;}
.ft15{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 3px;line-height: 19px;}
.ft16{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 18px;}
.ft17{font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 15px;}
.ft18{font: 11px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 14px;}
.ft19{font: 16px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 20px;}
.ft20{font: 16px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 19px;}
.ft21{font: bold 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 45px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft22{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 2px;line-height: 17px;}
.ft23{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 20px;}
.ft24{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 3px;line-height: 21px;}
.ft25{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 21px;}
.ft26{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 21px;}
.ft27{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 3px;line-height: 20px;}
.ft28{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft29{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 4px;line-height: 17px;}
.ft30{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 20px;line-height: 17px;}
.ft31{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 6px;line-height: 20px;}
.ft32{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 17px;}
.ft33{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 7px;line-height: 22px;}
.ft34{font: 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 2px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft35{font: bold 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 2px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft36{font: bold 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 1px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft37{font: bold 15px 'Arial';color: #00000a;margin-left: 4px;line-height: 18px;}
.ft38{font: bold 13px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 16px;}
.ft39{font: bold 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;line-height: 15px;}

.p0{text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p1{text-align: left;padding-left: 76px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p2{text-align: left;margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p3{text-align: left;margin-top: 39px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p4{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 26px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p5{text-align: justify;padding-left: 48px;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p6{text-align: left;padding-left: 75px;padding-right: 120px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -27px;}
.p7{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 18px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p8{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 125px;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p9{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 131px;margin-top: 13px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p10{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 21px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p11{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 131px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p12{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 130px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p13{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 122px;margin-top: 9px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p14{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p15{text-align: justify;padding-left: 48px;padding-right: 120px;margin-top: 23px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p16{text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p17{text-align: left;padding-left: 67px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p18{text-align: left;padding-left: 64px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p19{text-align: left;padding-left: 66px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p20{text-align: left;padding-left: 63px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p21{text-align: justify;padding-left: 48px;margin-top: 57px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p22{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 27px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p23{text-align: left;padding-left: 48px;padding-right: 128px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p24{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 123px;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -23px;}
.p25{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 120px;margin-top: 13px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -23px;}
.p26{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p27{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 128px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p28{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 174px;margin-top: 13px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p29{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 128px;margin-top: 11px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p30{text-align: justify;padding-left: 48px;margin-top: 11px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p31{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 122px;margin-top: 43px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p32{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 22px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p33{text-align: left;padding-left: 48px;padding-right: 143px;margin-top: 23px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p34{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 131px;margin-top: 14px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p35{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 134px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p36{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 142px;margin-top: 12px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p37{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 139px;margin-top: 13px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p38{text-align: justify;padding-left: 47px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p39{text-align: justify;padding-left: 95px;margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p40{text-align: justify;padding-left: 133px;padding-right: 139px;margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -38px;}
.p41{text-align: justify;padding-left: 133px;padding-right: 147px;margin-top: 7px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -38px;}
.p42{text-align: justify;padding-left: 133px;padding-right: 178px;margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -38px;}
.p43{text-align: left;padding-left: 133px;padding-right: 121px;margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -38px;}
.p44{text-align: justify;padding-left: 133px;padding-right: 140px;margin-top: 7px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -38px;}
.p45{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 120px;margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p46{text-align: justify;padding-left: 48px;margin-top: 13px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p47{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 121px;margin-top: 39px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p48{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 124px;margin-top: 31px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p49{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 172px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p50{text-align: justify;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 137px;margin-top: 9px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p51{text-align: left;padding-left: 72px;padding-right: 127px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-indent: -24px;}
.p52{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p53{text-align: left;padding-left: 48px;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p54{text-align: justify;padding-left: 48px;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p55{text-align: justify;padding-left: 24px;margin-top: 37px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p56{text-align: justify;margin-top: 19px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p57{text-align: right;padding-right: 149px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p58{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p59{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 57px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p60{text-align: right;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p61{text-align: right;padding-right: 111px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p62{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 66px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p63{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 18px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p64{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 37px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p65{text-align: right;padding-right: 105px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p66{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 25px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p67{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 4px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p68{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 31px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p69{text-align: left;padding-left: 120px;margin-top: 54px;margin-bottom: 0px;}

.td0{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 135px;vertical-align: bottom;}
.td1{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 208px;vertical-align: bottom;}
.td2{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 190px;vertical-align: bottom;}
.td3{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 227px;vertical-align: bottom;}
.td4{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 284px;vertical-align: bottom;}

.tr0{height: 19px;}
.tr1{height: 18px;}
.tr2{height: 27px;}
.tr3{height: 26px;}

.t0{width: 533px;margin-top: 81px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}
.t1{width: 533px;margin-top: 87px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}
.t2{width: 533px;margin-top: 80px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}
.t3{width: 533px;margin-top: 164px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}
.t4{width: 511px;margin-left: 120px;margin-top: 105px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}
.t5{width: 511px;margin-left: 120px;margin-top: 31px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}
.t6{width: 511px;margin-left: 120px;margin-top: 50px;font: 12px 'Arial';color: #00000a;}

</STYLE>
<!--prahlad
<style>
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;

        @frame header_frame {
            -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
        }
        @frame content_frame {
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
        }
        @frame footer_frame {
            -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
        }
    }
</style>-->
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV id="page_1">
<DIV id="dimg1">
<IMG src="template_images/template1x1.jpg" id="img1">
</DIV>


<DIV id="id_1">
<P class="p0 ft0">This is the last Will and Testament of __name__</P>
</DIV>
<DIV id="id_2">
<P class="p0 ft1">Willys</P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV id="page_2">


<P class="p1 ft1">LAST WILL AND TESTAMENT OF __NAME__</P>
<P class="p2 ft2">2</P>
<P class="p3 ft3">This will is made by me __name__ of __address__.</P>
<P class="p4 ft5"><SPAN class="ft2">1.</SPAN><SPAN class="ft4">Last will and testament</SPAN></P>
<P class="p5 ft3">I revoke all prior wills and testamentary acts.</P>
<P class="p4 ft5"><SPAN class="ft2">2.</SPAN><SPAN class="ft4">Executor</SPAN></P>
<P class="p5 ft3"><SPAN class="ft2">(a)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft6">I appoint my partner __partner1__ to be the executor of my Will.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p6 ft8"><SPAN class="ft2">(b)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft7">If __partner1__ is unable or unwilling to act as my executor I appoint in the alternative __exec1_name__ of __exec1_address__, to act as my executor.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p7 ft5"><SPAN class="ft2">3.</SPAN><SPAN class="ft4">Guardians</SPAN></P>
<P class="p8 ft8"><SPAN class="ft2">(a)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft9">I appoint __guardian_name__ of __guardian_address__ to be guardian of any minor children I have at the time of my death.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p9 ft11"><SPAN class="ft2">(b)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft10">This appointment applies only if the other parent of any minor children I have at the time of my death does not survive me or is unable to care for them.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p10 ft5"><SPAN class="ft2">4.</SPAN><SPAN class="ft4">Beneficiaries</SPAN></P>
<P class="p11 ft13"><SPAN class="ft2">(a)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft12">If my partner survives me by 30 days, I give my entire estate to __partner__.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p12 ft13"><SPAN class="ft2">(b)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft14">If my partner does not survive me by 30 days I give the balance of my estate in equal shares to my children __children__.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p13 ft11"><SPAN class="ft2">(c)</SPAN><SPAN class="ft15">If any of my children die before any gift to them takes effect and they are survived by children of their own (i.e. my grandchildren) then I give the share of my estate that would have gone to my deceased child to their children in equal shares.</SPAN></P>
<P class="p14 ft5"><SPAN class="ft2">5.</SPAN><SPAN class="ft4">Alternative beneficiaries</SPAN></P>
<P class="p15 ft16">If the gifts above fail to take effect then and only then I give my estate in equal shares to __children__.</P>
<P class="p10 ft5"><SPAN class="ft2">6.</SPAN><SPAN class="ft4">Funeral directions</SPAN></P>
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t0">
<TR>
    <TD class="tr0 td0"><P class="p16 ft17">___________________</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr0 td1"><P class="p17 ft17">___________________</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr0 td2"><P class="p18 ft18">___________________</P></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="tr1 td0"><P class="p16 ft17">Testator sign</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td1"><P class="p19 ft17">Witness 1 sign</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td2"><P class="p20 ft17">Witness 2 sign</P></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
<DIV id="page_3">


<P class="p1 ft1">LAST WILL AND TESTAMENT OF __NAME__</P>
<P class="p2 ft2">3</P>
```

...........

Comment: Show an example of template.htm

Comment: I've edited my question. At the end of first page, there is a paragraph element saying "Willys" which I want at the bottom.

Comment: Also, the page-breaks are not happening.